# How to delete just one record not all that have same content?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I echoed some data from database, now when I want to delete some records I have a problem.

Let say I have this records: 3, 3, 4, 6, 3.

```
<input type="radio" name="ocenaa" value="' . $row['slo'] . '">
```

When I want to delete the last record (3), it deletes me all records that have content 3...

My query:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM frend WHERE slo=('$_POST[ocenaa]')";
```

How can I delete just last record not all three?

Comment: Use a unique id for each row

Comment: How can you avoid a malicious user injecting `\';Drop table frend --` into their form submission? By reading about and learning how to avoid your gaping-wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability

Comment: Since MySQL doesn't guarantee an order without an ORDER BY clause, how do you know which is the 'last' one?

Comment: Please post your table schema. As @aynber said, you'll want to have a unique identifier for each row so you can manipulate them individually.

Comment: Throw in an AI id col

Comment: May be `DELETE ...  LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

It's doing what you would expect... Your data isn't unique. Use unique I'd for each row.

Is there any other way of identifying the row?

Comment: How do you know which row belongs to which student?

Comment: I have table for each one. I just have two students because I am making online gradebook for me and my friend.

Comment: You need to create another column in each table that has a unique Id with auto increment. That way you can use MAX in your SQL to delete the last inserted value with the selected value.

Comment: I created it. Is this right because it doesn't work:         $sql="DELETE FROM frend WHERE MAX(slo=('$_POST[ocenaa]'))";

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can tell you is to add a unique(auto_incrementing)_key to the structure phpMySql lets you do this easily. From then you would do this;
say the key was called id in php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM frend WHERE 1
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 1")

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

`mysql_query("DELETE FROM frend WHERE`id`= ".$result[0]);`
only call DELETE expressly from a unique table-row for the best desired result :).

I'm not a guru lol but this does sound like a familiar problem I ran into before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
$sql="DELETE FROM frend WHERE slo=('$_POST[ocenaa]') LIMIT 1;";
```

Also, you must at least consider using `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[ocenaa])` and better, MySQLi or PDO to formulate your query.